# Python script that creates new file and returns list of files

Tags: python, function, directory

I'm trying to create a python script called script.py with new_directory function that creates a new directory inside the current working directory, then creates a new empty file inside the new directory, and returns the list of files in that directory. 
The output I get is ["script.py"] which looks correct but gives me this error:

RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 5:
    directory = os.mkdir("/home/PythonPrograms")
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/home/PythonPrograms'
)

```
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):
  if os.path.isdir(directory) == False:
    directory = os.mkdir("/home/PythonPrograms")

  os.chdir("PythonPrograms")
  with open("script.py", "w") as file:
    pass

  # Return the list of files in the new directory
  return os.listdir("/home/PythonPrograms")

print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

How do I correct and why is this wrong?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of writing: `if os.path.isdir(directory) == False:`, please just write `if not os.path.isdir(directory)`.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Here's the error I get when running the script:
RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 5:
    directory = os.mkdir("/home/PythonPrograms")
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/home/PythonPrograms'
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it is hard to debug without the error. In the right cercumstances, your code will work without errors. As @Jack suggested, I suspect you're current directory is not `/home`. This means you've created a directory called `PythonPrograms` in `/home` directory. `os.chdir("PythonPrograms")` is trying to change the directory to `<currentDirectory>/PythonPrograms`, which doesn't exist.

I have tried to rework your code (without completely changing it), into something that should work in all cases. I think the lesson here is, work with the variables you already have (i.e. `directory`), rather than hardcoding it into the function.

```py
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):

  if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    # Create directory within current directory
    # This is working off the relative path (from your current directory)
    directory = os.mkdir(directory)

  # Create file if does not exist
  # this is a one-liner version of you with...pass statement
  open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'a').close()

  # Return the list of files in the new directory
  return os.listdir(directory)

print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @J.Warren
In theory it makes sense. I got an error after running though:

Error on line 17:
    print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
Error on line 12:
    open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'a').close()

Comment: Got it to work. Just had to specify the directory path. Thanks again @J.Warren

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error you're getting is because you're not able to switch directories to `PythonPrograms`? This would be because your python current working directory does not contain it. If you more explicitly write out the directory you want to switch to, for example putting `os.chdir("/home/PythonPrograms")`, then it may work for you.

Ideally you should give us any stack traces or more info on the errors, though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why in your code you have `with open("script.py", "w") as file: pass`,

but here is mt way:

```
import os

os.mkdir('.\\Newfolder') # Create a new folder called Newfolder in the current directory
open('.\\Newfolder\\file.txt','w').close() # Create a new file called file.txt into Newfolder
print(os.listdir('.')) # Print out all the files in the current directory
```

Comment: Presumably this would leave the file open. Using the context manager syntax closes the file again. `open('.\\Newfolder\\file.txt','w').close()` would fix this